# get profile picture of logged in user on Instagram

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to use **Instagram Basic Display API (V2)** to get username and user profile picture of user who logs into application.

I have given necessary permissions to the application for eg. **instagram_user_profile** & **instagram_user_media**, I am successfully getting username of the user but i am not getting any API end point which will return me user's profile picture.

following is the link I am referring to for Instagram Basic Display API
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api

I have tried to query the media node using following GET api listed in the documentation `https://graph.instagram.com/{userid}/media?access_token=IGQV....`
But in response i am able to get only data of Instagram POST of logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. Instagram Basic Display doesn't provide basic info like user display name and profile picture.

Even the known workarounds, like https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME/?__a=1, are not fully working anymore (think they added some IP filtering, because it works from my machine but if I deploy to an AWS Lambda it doesn't).

The only official way to get the user info that I know is the Instagram Graph API, but it's only for Instagram Business :(

Comment: thanks @Paulo César Coutinho yes it is true that Instagram do not provide access to profile picture. for my application i have used Instagram basic display api which gives me access to user basic display as well as access to photos of the user.